# Input field is not recognizing dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a reverse geolocation code which returns a formatted address to which i then dynamically add to a google map address field which should automatically update the map. The problem is that the only way the google map will update is if I add a space bar or any type of input in the input field as if it does not recognize the data i am dynamically adding via document.getElementById.('address').value=

I have tried to simulate key events to the input field to make it believe there was data added, I have tried to use the google api to just manually refresh the map which had no effect, I have tried to split the string being added after it was added to see if it recognizes a change, I have also tried to set the length of the input field to + 1 to see if that worked. I really have no clue what to do at this point. Here is my current attempt to make the input field recognize there is a value.

```
<span class="findme" id="find1"><i class="fa fa-compass" style="font-size:33px;color:green;"></i></span>      
<script>
var find1 = document.getElementById("find1");        
var info = document.getElementById("info");    
var selector = [];    
find1.addEventListener("click", function() {            
selector.push("jform_fulladdress");    
    getLocation();
}, false);            
function putInDom(address){    
  if(selector.length == 1){
    //one field for address
    var field = document.getElementById(selector[0]);
    field.value = address;
  }     
}

function getLocation(){
  if (navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getAddress);
  } else{
    info.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function getAddress(position){    
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lon = position.coords.longitude;    
  var apiurl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+lat+','+lon+'&sensor=true';    
  var url = 'ba-simple-proxy.php?url='+encodeURIComponent(apiurl);    
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();    
  xhr.open("GET", url);
  xhr.onload = function() {             
      if(this.status==200 && JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).contents.results.length > 0){
        var result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).contents.results[0].formatted_address;
        putInDom(result);
      } else {
        info.innerHTML = "Could not find your location.";
      }    
  }    
  xhr.send();
}        
jQuery('form').change(function() {
var splAd = document.getElementById('jform_fulladdress').value;
splAd = splAd.split(',').slice(0, 2).join(',');
document.getElementById('jform_maps_search').value= splAd;
document.getElementById('jform_fulladdress').value= splAd;

jQuery('jform_fulladdress')
  .trigger({
    type: 'keypress',
    which: character.charCodeAt(49)      
   });    
}).click(function() {
var splAd = document.getElementById('jform_fulladdress').value;
splAd = splAd.split(',').slice(0, 2).join(',');
 document.getElementById('jform_maps_search').value= splAd;
document.getElementById('jform_fulladdress').value= splAd;    
jQuery('jform_fulladdress')
  .trigger({
    type: 'keypress',
    which: character.charCodeAt(49)      
   });    
});    
</script>
```